# A real example of URL Namespace

Tags: django, url, namespaces, django-views

I am studying the Django documentation, but I encountered a part that I cannot understand: what is a real example of how use to use a namespace in a real problem. I know the syntax but I do not know the purpose of this.

Comment: I'm leaning Django now and I am bothered about this url namespacing and even unnecessary folder name inside templates. If there was a way for the url function in views to auto detect (context-aware) which template it is in, imho that should eliminate the necessity for this namespacing and prevent possible conflicts.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Typically, they are used to put each application's URLs into their own namespace. This prevents the `reverse()` Django function and the `{% url %}` template function from returning the wrong URL because the URL-pattern name happened to match in another app.

What I have in my project-level `urls.py` file is the following:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'main.views.main', name='main'),
    url(r'^login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name="login"),
    url(r'^logout$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
        {"next_page": "/"}, name="logout"),

# Admin
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

# Auto-add the applications.
for app in settings.LOCAL_APPS:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^{0}/'.format(app), include(app + '.urls', namespace=app)),
    )
```

Note the last section: this goes through the applications I have installed (`settings.LOCAL_APPS` is a setting I added that contains only my apps; it gets added to `INSTALLED_APPS` which has other things like South), looks for a `urls.py` in each of them, and imports those URLs into a namespace named after the app, and also puts those URLs into a URL subdirectory named after the app.

So, for example, if I have an app named `hosts`, and `hosts/urls.py` looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('hosts.views',
    url(r'^$', 'show_hosts', name='list'),
)
```

Now my `views.py` can call `reverse("hosts:list")` to get the URL to the page that calls `hosts.views.show_hosts`, and it will look something like `"/hosts/"`. Same goes for `{% url "hosts:list" %}` in a template. This way I don't have to worry about colliding with a URL named "list" in another app, and I don't have to prefix every name with `hosts_`.

Note that the login page is at `{% url "login" %}` since it wasn't given a namespace.

Comment: I see.. but this is the same as putting a name into a URL, right? Do the same job..

Comment: Now I saw the full answer... and it is awesome... If I got it right, you use namespace together with named URL.. so that you will not worry about if you have named two views from differents apps with the same name... is this right?

Comment: Pretty much. I'm sure there are other uses, and better ones, but this was a quick example.

Comment: What do I actually gain doing that? By using urls like "myns:myname" I force the user to include my application using namespace="myns". What's the real benefit above using "myns-myname" and don't relying on namespaces?

Answer (score 11):

Consider you are using a url pattern as below
`url(r'^login/',include('app_name', name='login'))` 
Also Consider you are using a third-party app like Django-RestFramework.
When you use the app, you have to declare the following line in URLs conf file of the project.

```
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

Now if you check the code of rest-framework, you will find the below code in urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login, login_kwargs, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
]
```

We have used 'login' name for a URL pattern in our project and the same name is being used by Django-rest-framework for one of their URL patterns. When you use reverse('login'), Django will get confused.

To resolve these kinds of issues, we use namespace.

```
@register.simple_tag
def optional_docs_login(request):
    """
    Include a login snippet if REST framework's login view is in the URLconf.
    """
    try:
        login_url = reverse('rest_framework:login')
    except NoReverseMatch:
        return 'log in'
```

URL names of a namespace will never collide with other namespaces.

A namespaced URL pattern can be reversed using 
`reverse('namespace:url_name')`

Comment: If your urls.py imports a class-based view that uses reverse(), you will get this error; using reverse_lazy() will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

We also make use of namespace within middleware to handle certain ones differently

```
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        try:
            if resolve(request.path).namespace == 'special_namespace':
                response['Custom-Header'] = 'Custom-Value'
            return response
        except Resolver404:
            return response
```