# NoReverseMatch exception in a simple Django app

Tags: python, django

Let me say upfront that I have read many threads relating to this exception on this forum and was still unable to find the solution. Not sure what am I missing.

Here is the urls.py in my app:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', PeopleList.as_view(), name='people_list'),
    )
```

And this is the template code that is generating error:

```
<a href="{% url 'people_list' %}">Index</a>
```

The error I get is

```
Reverse for 'people_list' with arguments '()' 
and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I read through many posts on this error and tried several things (restarting the webserver, changing to double quotes / single quotes / no quotes, etc). But I am not able to see the error.

This code is copied from [a CRUD example](http://www.pythondiary.com/tutorials/simple-crud-app-django.html) and I am using django 1.6.4.

The view code is:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from people.models import Category, Person
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from people.forms import CategoryForm, PersonForm
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class PeopleList(PersonMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'people/object_list.html'
```

Actually code is from the link: http://www.pythondiary.com/tutorials/simple-crud-app-django.html. But I am using django 1.6.

On change that I have done is from

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url, include
```

I changed to

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
```

Comment: Could you share the view or form code that you are using to pass `'people_list'` to your template?

Comment: ssbrewster,  replied to your question by adding code. I have also given the link to the tutorial from where I have copied this code.

Comment: @mht, check your `ROOT_URLCONF` in settings.py. Is it corresponds to your urls.py?

Comment: In C:\development\mysite\mysite\settings.py : ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'. The app in question "people" is in C:\development\mysite\people. So is there some additional entry needed in settings.py?

Comment: additionally, in mysite\urls.py, there is an entry: urlpatterns = patterns('',
 url(r'^people/', include('people.urls', namespace="people")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171570/a-real-example-of-url-namespace) for how to call an URL with a namespace.

Comment: thanks a lot. It was namespace that was causing the problem. The problem got resolved after I removed namespace="people" from the urlpatterns().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your base urls.py you included app's urls with namespace, so in template you should use namespace too.In your case: 
`<a href="{% url 'people:people_list' %}">Index</a>`.

More about namespaces: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces.

Comment: Also, people should be sure to use a colon after the URL namespace, in this case `people:`. I spent considerable time debugging when I used a dot (`.`) instead.