# django - when url namespace should be used?

Tags: django, url, namespaces

I mostly read that it should be used with 3td party apps. But if I have my own many local apps, does it make sense to give each its own namespace? 
  This way I can know which url belongs to which app. Rather then relying on "name "solely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A real example of URL Namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171570/a-real-example-of-url-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Typically namespacing would be useful if you need to reuse the apps (e.g. make a part of your app a module that you'd use in another app), or build sites that contain multiple apps (e.g. two projects sharing the same user database). Another case is if you want to keep specific features of your project well-separated, you could make them into separate apps with their own namespace and their own `urls.py`.

There may be a few cases, if you're using incorrectly namespaced apps as modules of your own app, where there'd be conflicts.

Namespacing `urls.py` isn't the only thing you should do to reuse apps: You may want to put all your templates and static files in subfolders, as the way they're collected flattens the structure. e.g. your templates would be in `my_project/my_app/templates/my_app/template.html`

If you are certain that what you are developing will be standalone, there may be no need for namespacing.