# How to fix NoReverseMatch on redirect

Tags: python, django

Why am I  getting

> Reverse for 'explorer_js' not found. 'explorer_js' is not a valid
>   view function or pattern name.

when calling the `select` view below?:

```
def explorer_js(request):
    activities = Activity.objects.all()
    fill_column = lambda attr : [getattr(activity, attr) for activity in activities]
    d = {
        'ids' : fill_column('id'),
        'dates_added' : fill_column('date_added'),
        'numbers' : fill_column('number'),
        'athletes' : fill_column('athlete'),
        'start_dates' : fill_column('start_date'),
        'names' : fill_column('name'),
        'countries' : fill_column('country'),
        'links' : fill_column('link'),
        'segment_efforts' : fill_column('segment_efforts'),
        'distances' : fill_column('distance'),
        'average_speeds' : fill_column('average_speed')
    }

    context = {'d': d}
    return render(request, 'explorer_api/explorer_js.html', context)

def select(request):
    """Filters explorer data and sends it to explorer again"""  
    return redirect('explorer_js')
```

The app's `urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'explorer_api'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page.
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('explorer_js/', views.explorer_js, name='explorer_js'),
    path('select/', views.select, name='select'),
]
```

Comment: You might have to do `redirect('explorer_api:explorer_js')` instead. That's how it works for me when I have different apps as part of my overall project.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Does it mean that if I had only one app in my project, `redirect('explorer_js')` would suffice?

Comment: I think [this Stack Overflow post on Django namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19171674/9374673) should help clear up any confusion. I think the main app that imports URLs from other apps doesn't require that kind of namespacing, so if `'explorer_js'` was in your primary `urls.py` you would be able to refer to it that way.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru Hi, since your comment has fixed OP's issue, please add your comment as an answer so that this question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `app_name` to refer to the namespace that that particular view is located in like so:

```
redirect('explorer_api:explorer_js')
```

This tells Django where to look for the view, so that in case you had, say, two different views in two different apps with the same name, such as `'login'`, Django can resolve which one you're referring to.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19171674/9374673) for a more in-depth explanation.