# Django 2.1 - What does namespace= do on an include in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I pretty much have `app_name` and namespaces working well, but I have a simple clarification - and I think this might be something that is in my 2.1 Django that might have been different in earlier Django versions.

I have an app named `route` and in its `urls.py` I have:

```
app_name = 'route'  
urlpatterns = [
    path('first', views.FirstView.as_view(), name='first-view'),
]
```

In my `views.py` and template files I use `route:first-view` in my `reverse()` calls and `{% url .. %}` calls and it all works.

My confusion is in my project wide `urls.py` where I say something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('route/', include('route.urls', namespace='route')),
]
```

The part that is making me crazy is that it appears that the `namespace=` parameter does absolutely nothing.  My code works the same if I leave it out or even if I say `namespace='abc'` - it seems to be 100% ignored by Django 2.1.

Also if I use `namespace='route'` without `app_name` being set, I get an error: `Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported`.

If `namespace=` is ignored - then I am happy just setting `app_name` - I will leave it off - It just seems like it must have a purpose that I just can't figure out.  Or maybe this is something unnecessary and from an earlier version of Django.

Note: I have looked at [a similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171570/a-real-example-of-url-namespace) but that example does not explain how namespace works when using `path`.  I try to avoid the url/regular expression pattern and use the simpler `path` pattern as much as possible.

Comment: There is also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `namespace` in the `include()` allows you to include the *same* app more than once, with a different namespace for each instance.

You can see an example [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls), where the `polls` app is included twice with two different namespaces.

If you only include `route.urls` once in your project, then the `namespace='route'` isn't required, and can be removed.

Comment: Thanks - this is getting me closer.  So, is it the case that the namespace= is overriding the app_name? Can I use namespace to override the app_name even if I am only including the app once?

Comment: If you do `namespace = 'mypolls'`, you are setting the *instance* namespace to `mypolls`. You can then reverse URLs with the instance namespace, e.g. `mypolls:index`. It hasn't overridden the *application* namespace - that remains as `polls`, so you can still reverse `polls:index`. See the [introduction to namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#introduction) for more information.

Comment: Thanks - this is the answer I needed.  The `namespace=` is a *additional* namespace that can be used either outside or within the app.  So If I were building something for reuse (i.e. like django_social) I might have a relatively obscure `app_name` and let the person including the social urls pick their own namespace when including the urls - this helps keep common app_names from colliding.  Got it.

Answer (score 0):

With namespace, you can do this in your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'portal:changepass' %}">Change pass</a>
```

If you have an other url with the same name "changepass" in an other app, you can do the same changing only the namespace:

```
<a href="{% url 'system:changepass' %}">Change pass</a>
```

i hope it will help ^^

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. You can already do `{% url 'portal:changepass' %}` and `{% url 'system:changepass' %}` when you set `app_name = 'portal'` and `app_name = 'system'` in the `urls.py` files.

Comment: It will work with app_name or namespace, if the namespace is "portal" and app_name is "portalllll" it will work with namespace "portal", you can see more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls